# Plotting attenuated wave with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, plot

I have the code (generously corrected by the stack)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{20}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,
declare function={pX=2;}]
 \begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=0]
 \draw (-pX,-pX) coordinate (bl1) -- (pX,-pX) coordinate (br1)
   -- (pX,pX) coordinate (tr1)  -- (-pX,pX) coordinate (tl1) -- cycle;
   \draw[stealth-stealth] (0,pX) node[below left]{$$}
   -- (0,0) --  (pX,0) node[below left]{$$};
   \pgflowlevelsynccm
 \end{scope}
 %\foreach \X in {bl,tl,br,tr}
 %{\draw[-latex] (\X1) -- ++ (1,0,0);}
 %
 %\draw (0,0,0) -- (4,0,0);
 % plane
  \fill[gray,fill opacity=0] (-1,-4,0) -- (7,-4,0) --
  (7,4,0) -- (-1,4,0) -- cycle;
 \begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=4]
  \draw (-pX,-pX) coordinate (bl2) -- (pX,-pX) coordinate (br2)
   -- (pX,pX) coordinate (tr2)  -- (-pX,pX) coordinate (tl2) -- cycle;
   \draw[stealth-stealth];
 \end{scope}
 \draw[-latex] (4,0,0) -- (5.5,0,0) node[below left]{$$};
 %\foreach \X in {bl,tl,br,tr}
 %{\draw[-latex] (\X2) -- ++ (1,0,0);}
  \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0]
   \begin{scope}
      \clip (0,-2) rectangle (4,3);
      \draw[densely dashed] (0,-2) -- (0,2);
      \foreach \X in {0.25,0.75,...,5}
       {\pgfmathsetmacro{\myrnd}{rnd*360}
       \foreach \Y in {-1.75,-1.25,...,1.75}
        {
        \draw[-stealth] ({\X-0.2*cos(\myrnd)},{\Y-0.2*sin(\myrnd)}) --
        ({\X+0.2*cos(\myrnd)},{\Y+0.2*sin(\myrnd)});
        }
        \draw[densely dashed] (\X+.25,-2) -- (\X+0.25,2);}
%       \foreach \X in {-2,-1.6,...,2}
%        {\draw (0,\X) parabola ++(5,1);}
   \end{scope} 
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}



\end{document}
```

which outputs
[image]
I'm wondering if it is possible to plot an incident polarised wave that looks like this, with wavelength equal to the separation between dashed lines, entering from the leftmost rectangle.
[image]
Then, as if the wave exits, starting from the right rectangle, it has a decaying, random amplitude, as if the space where the dashed lines are, sap energy and distort the wave. This is the end result I want
[image]

With the help of SchrodingersCat, I have

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
    \usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending}
    \usepackage{xparse}
    \usepackage{tikz}

    \usetikzlibrary{3d}
    \begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{20}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,
declare function={pX=2;}]
 \begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=0]
 \draw (-pX,-pX) coordinate (bl1) -- (pX,-pX) coordinate (br1)
   -- (pX,pX) coordinate (tr1)  -- (-pX,pX) coordinate (tl1) -- cycle;
   \draw[stealth-stealth] (0,pX) node[below left]{$$}
   -- (0,0) --  (pX,0) node[below left]{$$};
   \pgflowlevelsynccm
 \end{scope}
 %\foreach \X in {bl,tl,br,tr}
 %{\draw[-latex] (\X1) -- ++ (1,0,0);}
 %
 %\draw (0,0,0) -- (4,0,0);
 % plane
  \fill[gray,fill opacity=0] (-1,-4,0) -- (7,-4,0) --
  (7,4,0) -- (-1,4,0) -- cycle;
 \begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=4]
  \draw (-pX,-pX) coordinate (bl2) -- (pX,-pX) coordinate (br2)
   -- (pX,pX) coordinate (tr2)  -- (-pX,pX) coordinate (tl2) -- cycle;
   \draw[stealth-stealth];
 \end{scope}
 %\draw[-latex] (4,0,0) -- (5.5,0,0) node[below left]{$$};
  \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0]
   \begin{scope}
      \clip (0,-2) rectangle (4,3);
      \draw[densely dashed] (0,-2) -- (0,2);
      \foreach \X in {0.25,0.75,...,5}
       {\pgfmathsetmacro{\myrnd}{rnd*360}
       \foreach \Y in {-1.75,-1.25,...,1.75}
        {
        \draw[-stealth] ({\X-0.2*cos(\myrnd)},{\Y-0.2*sin(\myrnd)}) --
        ({\X+0.2*cos(\myrnd)},{\Y+0.2*sin(\myrnd)});
        }
        \draw[densely dashed] (\X+.25,-2) -- (\X+0.25,2);}
   \end{scope} 
  \end{scope}
%
\begin{scope}[shift={($(-4,0,0)-(0,0,0)$)}]
 \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0,dashed]
   \foreach \X in {0.1,0.3,...,3.2}
    {\begin{scope}
      \pgflowlevelsynccm
      \draw[-latex,thick] (1*\X,0) -- (1*\X,{-sin(\X*180)});
     \end{scope} 
    }
   \draw plot[smooth,domain=0:4,samples=41] (1*\x,{-sin(\x*180)});  
  \begin{scope}
   \pgflowlevelsynccm
   \draw[-latex,ultra thick,solid] (12.2,0) -- (12.8,0);
  \end{scope}
 \end{scope} 
 \begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=0]
   \foreach \X in {0.1,0.3,...,3.2}
    {\begin{scope}
      \pgflowlevelsynccm
      \draw[-latex,thick] (1*\X,0) -- (1*\X,{sin(\X*180)});
     \end{scope} 
    }
   \draw plot[smooth,domain=0:4,samples=41] (1*\x,{sin(\x*180)});   
 \end{scope} 
 \node at (1*3.5,1.75,0) {$$};
 \node at (1*3.5,0,-1.25) {$$};
\end{scope} 

%
\begin{scope}[shift={($(4,0,0)-(0,0,0)$)}]
 \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0,dashed]
   \foreach \X in {0.4,0.6,...,3}
    {\begin{scope}
      \pgflowlevelsynccm
      \draw[-latex,thick] (1*\X,0) -- (1*\X,{-.2*sin(\X*180)});
     \end{scope} 
    }
   \draw plot[smooth,domain=0:4,samples=41] (1*\x,{-.2*sin(\x*180)});  
  \begin{scope}
   \pgflowlevelsynccm
   \draw[-latex,ultra thick,solid] (12.2,0) -- (12.8,0);
  \end{scope}
 \end{scope} 
 \begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=0]
   \foreach \X in {0.4,0.6,...,3}
    {\begin{scope}
      \pgflowlevelsynccm
      \draw[-latex,thick] (1*\X,0) -- (1*\X,{.5*sin(\X*180)});
     \end{scope} 
    }
   \draw plot[smooth,domain=0:4,samples=41] (1*\x,{.5*sin(\x*180)});   
 \end{scope} 
 \node at (1*3.5,1.75,0) {$$};
 \node at (1*3.5,0,-1.25) {$$};
\end{scope} 

\end{tikzpicture}






\end{document}
```

which outputs
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do that is

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{50}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
 \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0,dashed]
   \foreach \X in {0.1,0.3,...,3.9}
    {\begin{scope}
      \pgflowlevelsynccm
      \draw[-latex,thick] (3*\X,0) -- (3*\X,{-2*sin(\X*180)});
     \end{scope} 
    }
   \draw plot[smooth,domain=0:4,samples=41] (3*\x,{-2*sin(\x*180)});    
  \begin{scope}
   \pgflowlevelsynccm
   \draw[-latex,ultra thick,solid] (12.2,0) -- (12.8,0);
  \end{scope}
 \end{scope} 
 \begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=0]
   \foreach \X in {0.1,0.3,...,3.9}
    {\begin{scope}
      \pgflowlevelsynccm
      \draw[-latex,thick] (3*\X,0) -- (3*\X,{2*sin(\X*180)});
     \end{scope} 
    }
   \draw plot[smooth,domain=0:4,samples=41] (3*\x,{2*sin(\x*180)}); 
 \end{scope} 
 \node at (3*3.5,2.5,0) {$\vec B$};
 \node at (3*3.5,0,-2.5) {$\vec E$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can add this to your picture like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{20}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,
declare function={pX=2;}]
 \begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=0]
 \draw (-pX,-pX) coordinate (bl1) -- (pX,-pX) coordinate (br1)
   -- (pX,pX) coordinate (tr1)  -- (-pX,pX) coordinate (tl1) -- cycle;
   \draw[stealth-stealth] (0,pX) node[below left]{$$}
   -- (0,0) --  (pX,0) node[below left]{$$};
   \pgflowlevelsynccm
 \end{scope}
 %\foreach \X in {bl,tl,br,tr}
 %{\draw[-latex] (\X1) -- ++ (1,0,0);}
 %
 %\draw (0,0,0) -- (4,0,0);
 % plane
  \fill[gray,fill opacity=0] (-1,-4,0) -- (7,-4,0) --
  (7,4,0) -- (-1,4,0) -- cycle;
 \begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=4]
  \draw (-pX,-pX) coordinate (bl2) -- (pX,-pX) coordinate (br2)
   -- (pX,pX) coordinate (tr2)  -- (-pX,pX) coordinate (tl2) -- cycle;
   \draw[stealth-stealth];
 \end{scope}
 \draw[-latex] (4,0,0) -- (5.5,0,0) node[below left]{$$};
  \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0]
   \begin{scope}
      \clip (0,-2) rectangle (4,3);
      \draw[densely dashed] (0,-2) -- (0,2);
      \foreach \X in {0.25,0.75,...,5}
       {\pgfmathsetmacro{\myrnd}{rnd*360}
       \foreach \Y in {-1.75,-1.25,...,1.75}
        {
        \draw[-stealth] ({\X-0.2*cos(\myrnd)},{\Y-0.2*sin(\myrnd)}) --
        ({\X+0.2*cos(\myrnd)},{\Y+0.2*sin(\myrnd)});
        }
        \draw[densely dashed] (\X+.25,-2) -- (\X+0.25,2);}
   \end{scope} 
  \end{scope}
%
\begin{scope}[shift={($(-5,0,0)-(0,0,0)$)}]
 \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0,dashed]
   \foreach \X in {0.1,0.3,...,3.9}
    {\begin{scope}
      \pgflowlevelsynccm
      \draw[-latex,thick] (1*\X,0) -- (1*\X,{-sin(\X*180)});
     \end{scope} 
    }
   \draw plot[smooth,domain=0:4,samples=41] (1*\x,{-sin(\x*180)});  
  \begin{scope}
   \pgflowlevelsynccm
   \draw[-latex,ultra thick,solid] (12.2,0) -- (12.8,0);
  \end{scope}
 \end{scope} 
 \begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=0]
   \foreach \X in {0.1,0.3,...,3.9}
    {\begin{scope}
      \pgflowlevelsynccm
      \draw[-latex,thick] (1*\X,0) -- (1*\X,{sin(\X*180)});
     \end{scope} 
    }
   \draw plot[smooth,domain=0:4,samples=41] (1*\x,{sin(\x*180)});   
 \end{scope} 
 \node at (1*3.5,1.75,0) {$\vec B$};
 \node at (1*3.5,0,-1.25) {$\vec E$};
\end{scope} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is what I am looking for, but how can I insert this into my original frame? I have added a crudely drawn picture for reference

Comment: @rodger_kicks Sure, I added it.

Comment: Thanks so much. Okay. I have edited my post. I'm trying now to make the second wave have a random amplitude. I tried using /myrnd but it doesn't work. Is there something easier I can use?

Comment: @rodger_kicks Would you mind asking a separate question on this? Asking questions is free, and I am afraid that after too many edits the answer will become useless for others.